# Miniature PHP webserver not accepting connections on anything other than 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: php, sockets

I've created a miniature 'web server' that simply returns one message to any request sent to it on port 80. I can connect to it via http://127.0.0.1/ but when I try to connect to it with my actual IP address, nothing comes through.

Code:

```
# config
$conn_ip = "127.0.0.1"; // probably localhost
$conn_port = 80; // port to host 'server' on
$conn_max  = 5; // max connections to accept
# end config

$output = 'blah';

# prepare php script
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
# end

# setup the socket
$server = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($server,$conn_ip,$conn_port);
socket_listen($server,$conn_max);
# end

print "listening on port 80...\n\n";

# loop
while (true) {
 if (($new_sock = socket_accept($server)) !== NULL) {
  print("got connection...\n");
  socket_write($new_sock,$output,strlen($output));
  socket_close($new_sock);
     }
}
# end

?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've tried 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 and both times it just hangs while loading the page and I get no connection notification in the console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
$conn_ip = "127.0.0.1"; // probably localhost
```

to

```
$conn_ip = 0;
```

---

- 127.0.0.1 means that your "webserver" will only listen for connections only
  on 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
- 0 means that your "webserver" will listen on each and every IP of
  your computer

Comment: Tried that as well, same problem. :(

Comment: Try connecting to it from the same machine using the machine's ip. (for example http://192.168.0.2 ) Does that work?

Comment: Perhaps only other machines can access it by my IP?

Comment: Than it is a firewall problem. What OS?

Comment: Can other machines on the same access it by IP? If they can, than you should start looking at your router. (um... DMZ never worked for me... I always ended up using port forwarding... :p)

Comment: I have fixed it. I thought being in the DMZ would be enough but I had to change some router settings. So sorry for wasting everybody's time.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as a solution, since I pointed you in the right direction. (And you need to change that line anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your [socket bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php) to:

```
socket_bind ($server, 0,$conn_port);
```

By specifying a $conn_ip, you are only binding to that interface.  In this case, you are binding to the loopback.  This is the default for testing, as you may not want to allow the world to connect to your service when you first start writing it.

Comment: There is no apparent change when I swap $conn_ip with a 0.